# Python Poetry runtimeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I'm trying to install packages with poetry. Running `poetry install --with dev` and getting error:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 84 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing google-auth (2.19.1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Hash for google-auth (2.19.1) from archive google_auth-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl not found in known hashes (was: sha256:debadd08edb60eed0afa5c23f5555661f00ded703f4cad379b423bc88e475f22)

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:818 in _validate_archive_hash
      814│         archive_hash: str = "sha256:" + get_file_hash(archive)
      815│         known_hashes = {f["hash"] for f in package.files if f["file"] == archive.name}
      816│ 
      817│         if archive_hash not in known_hashes:
    → 818│             raise RuntimeError(
      819│                 f"Hash for {package} from archive {archive.name} not found in"
      820│                 f" known hashes (was: {archive_hash})"
      821│             )
      822│
```

OS: MacOS Monterey
Installed with `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`, not pip